# octave is slow; suggestions

Tags: performance, matlab, octave, computation

Have run the following code in both Octave 4.0.0 and MATLAB 2014.  Time difference is silly, i.e. more than two orders of magnitude.  Running on Windows laptop.  What can be done to improve Octave computational speed?

```
startTime = cputime;
iter = 1;  % iter is the current iteration of the loop
itSum = 0;  % itSum is the sum of the iterations
stopCrit = sqrt(275);  % stopCrit is the stopping criteria for the while loop
while itSum < stopCrit
   itSum = itSum + 1/iter;
   iter = iter + 1;
   if iter > 1e7, break, end
end
iter-1
totTime = cputime - startTime
```

Octave: totTime ~ 112

MATLAB: totTime < 0.4

Comment: I don't know if you noticed that your function calculate the sum of harmonic serie. So if you have a lot of iterations you have better to use sum(1./(1:exp(stopCrit)) for example and then adjust the sum until that sum(1./(1:#iteration)) = stopCrit.

Answer (score 1):

It takes a lot of iterations in the loop to compute the results in your code. Vectorizing the code will help speed up a lot. My following code do exactly what you did, but vectorize the computation quite a bit. See if it helps.

```
startTime = cputime;
iter = 1;  % iter is the current iteration of the loop
itSum = 0;  % itSum is the sum of the iterations
stopCrit = sqrt(275);  % stopCrit is the stopping criteria for the while loop
step=1000;
while(itSum < stopCrit && iter <= 1e7)
    itSum=itSum+sum(1./(iter:iter+step));
    iter = iter + step+ 1;
end
iter=iter-step-1;
itSum=sum(1./(1:iter));
for i=(iter+1):(iter+step)
    itSum=itSum+1/i;
    if(itSum+1/i>stopCrit)
        iter=i-1;
        break;
    end
end
totTime = cputime - startTime
```

My runtime is only about 0.6 second using the above code. If you do not care about exactly when the loop stops, the following code is even faster:

```
startTime = cputime;
iter = 1;  % iter is the current iteration of the loop
itSum = 0;  % itSum is the sum of the iterations
stopCrit = sqrt(275);  % stopCrit is the stopping criteria for the while loop
step=1000; 
while(itSum < stopCrit && iter <= 1e7)
    itSum=itSum+sum(1./(iter:iter+step));
    iter = iter + step+ 1;
end
iter=iter-step-1;
totTime = cputime - startTime
```

My runtime is only about 0.35 second in latter case.

Comment: A little confusing because your code does steps of length `step+1`

Comment: @Daniel, you are right. The point of my code was just to illustrate vectorizing the code could speed up quite a bit. Besides the step=1001, there are also many way to improve my code, such as tuning the step size, using bisection to find the last place `itSum<stopCrit` after the first loop and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try:

```
    itSum = sum(1./(1:exp(stopCrit)));
    %start the iteration
    iter  = exp(stopCrit-((stopCrit-itSum)/abs(stopCrit-itSum))*(stopCrit-itSum));
    itSum = sum(1./(1:iter))
```

With this methode you will only have 1 or 2 iteration. But of course you sum each time the whole array.